# Activity navigation with animation misbehaving

Tags: java, android, animation

Why does the First activity still shows up in the animation of [Second Activity --> First Activity].

[image]

Here are the animation xml files:

**slide_up.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    >
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.5"
        android:toAlpha="1"/>
</set>
```

**slide_down.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    >
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0.5"/>
</set>
```

Here is my java code:

**FirstActivity.java**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, PokeList.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,R.anim.no_animation);
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.no_animation);
```

> Supposedly the Second Activity is the only one moving up and down

Comment: and why not simply `finish()`? with startActivity you are creating new one

Comment: which part should I put finish();